# Measure number of HTTP requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I'm trying to collect performance data for our site. One of the metrics I'd like to measure is the number of http requests needed for a certain URL, e.g. ProductsController#show. What can I use to collect that data?

EDIT: To clarify, I mean counting the number of requests made client-side in the browser. E.g. number of images, scripts, css, etc. loaded.

Right now the only way I know of to grab this information is within a browser's debugger, such as the network timeline in Chrome's web inspector. There I can see the number of requests made, size of the request, and what was fetched before and after document.load.

The web inspector would be fine for a single, static page, but I'm trying to get an average of all pages under a certain route, such as products/{product_id}.

I don't believe Google Analytics can track http requests, and I'm wondering if there's a server-side solution or service for tracking/aggregating this kind of performance data.

Comment: OP, can you explain what you mean by `the number of http requests needed for a certain URL`? Need for a certain URL to do what?

Comment: Are you talking about the number of client-side AJAX requests issued, on top of the initial request to reach that controller/action?

Comment: You could set up a temporary route in your routes file and view the hits with Google analytics.

Comment: Google analytics should do the trick.